# How to capture launched finished activity in Android?

Tags: android, events, android-intent, android-activity

I need to do something ( like show an alert ) after my activity launched completely.

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
>    startActivity(intent);

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it in the onCreate of the SignInActivity class as the the first one will go to background and will no longer be able to display stuff on the screen, at least not directly

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem then!!

You can use the **onCreate**, **onResume** of *started activity*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class); startActivity(intent);
```

after this in `SignInActivity` use your alert

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    // Put your alert as the last statement of this method
}
```

### OR

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    // put your alert here 
    super.onResume();
}
```

**Note:** onResume is called every time the activity is resumed

Comment: my code is like this '   final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        String uriString = uri.toString();
        String extension = uriString.substring(uriString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        intent.setClass(this, extensionToActivity.get(extension));' so i should fire an event inside the oncreat class , yea?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) document from the official Android docs. As you can see you will receive a callback to one of three methods as your activity launches. If you only want to show it when the activity is first shown you can show the alert dialog in the onCreate call. You could also place it in the onResume call if you would like the dialog to show every time the user leaves this activity and comes back to it. Read through the doc, you'll have a better understanding of how an activity lives inside your application. Below is a quick example of where to place the code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Hello Android")
            .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot now i got this, so i should fire an event inside oncreate function and do something, how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? What type of event? After you launch the SignInActivity class using the Intent in your question you can show an alert dialog by placing the code above inside the SignInActivity.